# This or It? Which one is appropriate?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference

Which one is better? It or This? What is the difference between them?

> Trying to master the art of walking in high heels, women put a real
> strain on their legs. Because of **this**, some females suffer from
> excruciating pain in their knees when they get older.

> Trying to master the art of walking in high heels, women put a real
> strain on their legs. Because of **it**, some females suffer from
> excruciating pain in their knees when they get older.

Comment: What this means is "knee pain in older women causes them to put strain on their legs when wearing high heels". I think you mean "walking in high heels places strain on the legs, which leads to knee pain when they get older". if this is what you meant, change it to "This is because..." to "Because of this, ....".

Comment: @JavaLatte Thanks you, I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We generally use **it** to refer to a noun that was used in an earlier sentence:

> The heart is the central organ in our bodies. **It** is used to pump oxygen around the body through the bloodstream. (It refers back to The heart)

We generally use **this** to refer back to whole clauses and sentences:

> More and more people are discovering that Tai Chi is one of the most valuable forms of exercise. **This** has led to a big demand for classes. (This refers back to a whole sentence.)

In your sentence, you are referring back to the whole sentence, so **this** is the better choice. You can read more about this subject in the [Cambridge Dictionary guide to grammar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/it-this-and-that-in-paragraphs)

Answer (score 0):

I would put "this".  It makes your writing sound more professional.

(sorry, that's all I have.  I go by the feel of writing rather than definite rules.  Also, if this isn't how you're supposed to answer on this forum, let me know.)

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Salocor. I agree with you that **this** is the better choice, but we prefer answers that provide references to back up opinions, so I'm not going to upvote your answer.

Comment: Alright sounds good.  Thanks for letting me know!  (I also really appreciate the "I'm not going to upvote" vs the "downvote" mentality :D)

Comment: You are welcome. I always go easy the first time. But next time..... mwahahahahaha!

Comment: Actually, the correct grammar would be simply hahaha.  Jk.

Comment: https://www.lexico.com/definition/mwahahaha ... back up your opinions with references ;-)

Comment: Ouch.  Can't beat that.  :)