# It's all/this is all pointless

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which works better: it's all pointless, or this is all pointless?
Business owners often think, "Social media do not bring new customers, so it's all/this is all pointless."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between 'it' and 'this'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24981/) Or [This or It? Which one is appropriate?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/273408/) Or [difference between "it" vs "this" vs "that"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150296/). Or ["It" instead of "this/that"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/262531/). Or [This or It? Which one is appropriate?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/273408/) Or....

Comment: Have you [done any research](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "it's all pointless" and "this is all pointless" are grammatically correct and convey the same general meaning. However, "this is all pointless" may be considered slightly more formal and emphasizes the specific situation being discussed, while "it's all pointless" is more conversational and doesn't emphasize the situation as much.

In the context of business owners thinking that social media doesn't bring new customers, "it's all pointless" might be more appropriate because it is more concise and casual, which fits with the tone of a business owner thinking to themselves. "This is all pointless" could also be used, but it might seem more formal for this context.